# How to keep 1st occurrence and remove all other following occurrences?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying trying to plot identifiers under specified conditions; however, I'm not able to stop the script after finding the first occurrence of the specified condition (H2_RG -below).

```
//@version=4
study("Optimus Prime", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

//H0_RG conditions and declarations
H0_RG = open > close

//H1_RG conditions and declarations
H1_RG = H0_RG[1] and open < close

//H2_RG conditions and declarations
H2_RG = high[barssince(H1_RG)] < high and low[barssince(H1_RG)] <= low

plotshape(H1_RG, color=color.red, style=shape.arrowdown)
plotshape(H2_RG, color=color.yellow, style=shape.arrowdown)
```

With this script, I'm getting multiple occurrences of H2_RG plotted, but only want the first occurrence following H1_RG. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable that indicates if the condition has occured before. Then check the value of that variable in your H2_RG condition.

Following code will only plot H2_RG once.

```
//@version=4
study("Optimus Prime", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

var isH2occured = false

//H0_RG conditions and declarations
H0_RG = open > close

//H1_RG conditions and declarations
H1_RG = H0_RG[1] and open < close

//H2_RG conditions and declarations
H2_RG = not isH2occured and high[barssince(H1_RG)] < high and low[barssince(H1_RG)] <= low

if (H2_RG)
    isH2occured := true

plotshape(H1_RG, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small)
plotshape(H2_RG, color=color.yellow, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Baris!  Adding those lines to the script removes all occurrences of H2_RG. Just experimenting to block consecutive plots of H2_RG, I added the following to my original script:  H2_RG =  open[1] < close[1] and high[barssince(H1_RG)] < high and low[barssince(H1_RG)] <= low; however, the H2_RG bar would still be plotted, regardless of open < close. Now I'm trying to code a counting of bars to find H2_RG as a possible work around.

Comment: Hi @slebl29, please ask one question per post and please attach a screenshot of your chart. Otherwise, if I edit my answer regarding your comments, it would be difficult to follow for future readers.